# Rails how to query has_many instance in condition of the instance not exist

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Please help!

I need to combine those query clauses below into one.

```
Foo.where('bar_id IS NULL')
Foo.joins(:bar).where('bar.daily_budget > bar.daily_cost')
```

When the `joins(:bar)` in clause, `bar_id IS NULL` records will be filtered.

it's not quite that simple to combine like this below, this `bar_id IS NULL` will be filtered.

```
Foo.joins(:bar).where('bar.daily_budget > bar.daily_cost').where('bar_id IS NULL')
```

What i want result is more like

```
bar_id is null or (bar_id is not null AND bars.daily_budget > bars.daily_cost)
```

The Foo result need to have bar_id is null, and bars.daily_budget > bars.daily_cost if bar exist at time same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually want is SQL UNION.

You can use `#or` query method. Trick is, you will have to use `joins(:bar)` at both ends for *Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible.*

```
Foo.joins(:bar).where(:bar_id => nil)
               .or(Foo.join(:bar).where('bar.daily_budget > bar.daily_cost'))
# SELECT `foos`.* FROM `foos` INNER JOIN `bar` on `foos.bar_id` = `bar.id` WHERE(`foos`.`bar_id` is NULL OR bar.daily_budget > bar.daily_cost)
```

**Note**: QueryMethod `or` was added in Rails 5.

**Update** : As DanneManne answered, above won't work because `.joins(:bar).where(:bar_id => nil)` will actually give nothing on INNER JOIN. What is required is LEFT JOIN which can be done by:

```
Foo.left_outer_joins(:bar).where('foo.bar_id is null or bar.daily_budget > bar.daily_cost')
SELECT `foos`.* from `foos` LEFT OUTER JOIN `bar` ON `foos`.`bar_id` = `bar`.`id` WHERE (foo.bar_id is null or bar.daily_budget > bar.daily_cost)
```

Comment: But `Foo.joins(:bar).where(bar_id: nil)` is incompatible. The `where(:bar_id => nil)` result are filtered.
I tried  `Foo.where(bar_id: nil).or(Foo.joins(:bar).where('bar.daily_budget > bar.daily_cost'))`  in console, then i got those error `ArgumentError: Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:joins]`.

Comment: Try `Foo.left_outer_joins(:bar).where('foo.bar_id is null or bar.daily_budget > bar.daily_cost')`

Answer (score 1):

The problem with calling `.joins(:bar)` is that it will by default create an `INNER JOIN` database query. And when that happens, no records where `bar_id` is null, will be included in the result. And specifying `where(bar_id: null)` will not change that.

However, you can work around this problem by passing a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` string to the `joins` method instead of the symbol, and work from there. For example:

```
Foo.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN bar ON foo.bar_id = bar.id')
   .where('foo.bar_id IS NULL OR bar.daily_budget > bar.daily_cost')
```

Note that the table names in your case are most likely plural so make sure that the query matches your environment.

Comment: Thank you mention to `LEFT OUTER JOIN `, its works. But  @kiddorails answer is shorter `Foo.left_outer_joins(:bar)`.

Answer (score 0):

`joins` in Rails is `INNER JOIN`
What you need is `OUTER JOIN`